# Python: User input in a list aligns to index in the second list, output second list element

Tags: python, list, iteration

New programmer here!

I have two lists.
list1
list2
I need to lookup a name in list1 and then print its corresponding index from list2

**#my thinking**

#Get user input

#check input of user name against the name list (validation needs to occur here, when loop?)

#if the validation fails have the person reenter the name correctly

#if the validation succeeds then we continue with the program

#use the index of the input name correlate to the index of that persons phone number

#output Name and phone number

I believe my logic is okay on this, but its the code that I'm really struggling with. I have done work from Python Crash Course on lists, I've done work from Programming Logic and Design 5th edition, and Introduction to Computation and Programming using Python. However, I can't seem to find much where they are doing anything remotely similar to this.

Thanks for any help/advice you can give!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help you:

```
list1 = ['A','B','C'] #Name list
list2 = [985,900,876] #Phone Number list

while True:
    name = input("Name")
    if name in list1:
        index = list1.index(name)
        print(f"Name = {name} , Phone Number = {list2[index]}")
        break 
    else:
        print("Invalid input")
```

Output:

```
Name>? A
Name = A , Phone Number = 985
```

Comment: I was initally set on using a for loop then I watched a video by mulzy on YT, but had never used a while loop.
is the index=list1.index(name) Pulling that index number as a reference to help call it's corresponding piece from the other list?

Comment: Yes. That's what it does. And this while loop is an infinite loop and it only breaks when the user enters a valid input. Just copy paste my code into your python editor and let me know whether it works.

Comment: Great, again I just want to make sure I understand. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is much more easy with a dictionary:

```
list1 = [a,b,c]
list2 = [d,e,f]
dic = {}
for i in list1:
    for j in list2:
        dic[i] = j
```

This wil put every name from list1 in the dictionary.

```
while True:
    inp = input("Give a name please: ")
    if inp not in dic.keys():
        continue
    print(inp, str(dic[inp]))
    break
```

Comment: I've only read about dictionaries, I've not written anything with them at this  point. So you are setting the index from the dictionary = to the index from j then having it print the corresponding parts?

Comment: Yes, I kind of make a sort of link between the name and the phonenumber. When you call the dicionary[name], that puts out the linked number so in this case the phonenumber.

Comment: I see, I'm sure I'll be using dictionaries in some way/shape/form soon enough! Thanks!